# How to use pagination on HTML tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I am trying to use this Pagination [library](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) in my HTML table page (specifically light theme) but somehow I am not able to understand how to plugin this library in such a way in my HTML page so that I can have pagination code working in my HTML table..

Right now, I have HTML table without any pagination code working so my below HTML code will show you a table with all the rows in one page which is not what I want...

I want to show 6 items in my table in one page by using above pagination javascript.. And as soon as I click on second pagination tab, it should show me next six items and keep on going until it is finished..

Below is my full HTML code in which I have tried using the same above pagination javascript but it doesn't work for me..

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
<link href="../simplePagination.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <style type="text/css">
table {
    width: 40em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    }

    thead {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    }

    td {
    width: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    }

    tbody {
    background: #ccc;
    }

    </style>

    <script>

function test(pageNumber)
{

  var page="#page-id-"+pageNumber;
  $('.select').hide()
  $(page).show()

}

</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
    <table class="paginated">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>

                <th>B</th>

                <th>C</th>

                <th>D</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<div id="choose">
</div>


    <script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#choose').pagination({
            items: 20,
            itemsOnPage: 2,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber){test(pageNumber)}
        });
    });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any simple jsfiddle example basis on my above HTML code and also combined with above pagination javascript will help me understand better in how to imlement this js on the HTML tables..

Thanks for the help..

**NOTE:-**

**I am only interested in simplePagination.js solution only which I am currently trying to implement**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a very simple and effective utility build in jquery to implement pagination on html table http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Download the plugin from http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

After adding this plugin add following code in head script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwin.. But I am specifically interested in that pagination library javascript solution.. Thanks for the help anyways...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function                   gives me this error. i also include plugin file but still got this error

Comment: Use jQuery (1.2.1 or higher)

Comment: That website is down.

Comment: Seems like the website does not exist any more

Answer (score 54):

Many times we might want to perform Table pagination using jquery.Here i ll give you the answer and reference link

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#data').after('<div id="nav"></div>');
        var rowsShown = 4;
        var rowsTotal = $('#data tbody tr').length;
        var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
        for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
            var pageNum = i + 1;
            $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNum+'</a> ');
        }
        $('#data tbody tr').hide();
        $('#data tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
        $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
        $('#nav a').bind('click', function(){

            $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
            var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
            var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
            $('#data tbody tr').css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
                    css('display','table-row').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
        });
    });
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9d1ewsh/

Comment: ya nice. if anyone wants without a plugin

Comment: Thanks for this.. one issue I am facing is when it paginates the scroll position resets to top.. any solution for that ?

Comment: add an e.preventDefault(); right after the 'click' event to stop scrolling upwards

Comment: Brilliant! Had to modify it a little as I needed my pages to change based on clicking next or previous, but this was an excellent starting point!

Comment: For anybody wondering how to stop the scroll position from resetting to the top, change the **href="#"** in this line **$('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNum+'</a> ');** to **href="javascript:void()"**. It prevents it from performing any default action.

Comment: can i ask how to add prev and next button to your code ?? thanks

Answer (score 12):

For me, best and simplest way, Bootply
http://www.bootply.com/lxa0FF9yhw#

First include Bootstrap to your project

Then include javascript file in which you write this code:

```
    $.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            perPage: 7,
            showPrevNext: false,
            hidePageNumbers: false
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

    var listElement = $this;
    var perPage = settings.perPage; 
    var children = listElement.children();
    var pager = $('.pager');

    if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
        children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
    }

    if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
        pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
    }

    var numItems = children.size();
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

    pager.data("curr",0);

    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }

    var curr = 0;
    while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        curr++;
    }

    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }

    pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
    pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    if (numPages<=1) {
        pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }
    pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");

    children.hide();
    children.slice(0, perPage).show();

    pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
        var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
        goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
        previous();
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
        next();
        return false;
    });

    function previous(){
        var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }

    function next(){
        goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }

    function goTo(page){
        var startAt = page * perPage,
            endOn = startAt + perPage;

        children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();

        if (page>=1) {
            pager.find('.prev_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
        }

        if (page<(numPages-1)) {
            pager.find('.next_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.next_link').hide();
        }

        pager.data("curr",page);
        pager.children().removeClass("active");
        pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");

    }
};
```

You need to give an id to the tbody of your table and to add a 'div' after the table for the pagination

```
     <table class="table" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>...</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTableBody">
            </tbody>
       </table>
       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
           <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
       </div>
```

When your table's data is loaded, just call this

```
$('#myTableBody').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});
```

where the 'perPage' value is to set how many elements per page you want to have.

Comment: I am trying to this code. but every-time I run it I get this error in the console `TypeError: listElement.children is not a function` I tried to end my code with `(jQuery);` since I put the code in a separate file but still getting the same error.

Comment: did you include it in your html?

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a whole lot of time.

Answer (score 11):

**Pure js**.  Can apply it to multiple tables at once.  Aborts if only one page is required.  I used anushree as my starting point.

Sorry to the asker, obviously this is not a simplePagignation.js solution.  However, it's the top google result when you type "javascript table paging", and it's a reasonable solution to many who may be considering a library but unsure whether to go that route or not.

**EDITED** to account for the case of no `<thead>` tag.

Use like this:

```
addPagerToTables('#someTable', 4);
```

Requires no libraries or css (though have a visit at my amateur [glimp](https://github.com/paulwilcox/glimp) project for code doing something deeper.  Give a star if you desire to provide a much needed boosting of spirits).

The code (with sample table):

```js
addPagerToTables('#someTable', 4);

function addPagerToTables(tables, rowsPerPage = 10) {

    tables = 
        typeof tables == "string"
      ? document.querySelectorAll(tables)
      : tables;

    for (let table of tables) 
        addPagerToTable(table, rowsPerPage);

}

function addPagerToTable(table, rowsPerPage = 10) {

    let tBodyRows = getBodyRows(table);
    let numPages = Math.ceil(tBodyRows.length/rowsPerPage);

    let colCount = 
      [].slice.call(
          table.querySelector('tr').cells
      )
      .reduce((a,b) => a + parseInt(b.colSpan), 0);

    table
    .createTFoot()
    .insertRow()
    .innerHTML = `<td colspan=${colCount}><div class="nav"></div></td>`;

    if(numPages == 1)
        return;

    for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {

        let pageNum = i + 1;

        table.querySelector('.nav')
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            `<a href="#" rel="${i}">${pageNum}</a> `        
        );

    }

    changeToPage(table, 1, rowsPerPage);

    for (let navA of table.querySelectorAll('.nav a'))
        navA.addEventListener(
            'click', 
            e => changeToPage(
                table, 
                parseInt(e.target.innerHTML), 
                rowsPerPage
            )
        );

}

function changeToPage(table, page, rowsPerPage) {

    let startItem = (page - 1) * rowsPerPage;
    let endItem = startItem + rowsPerPage;
    let navAs = table.querySelectorAll('.nav a');
    let tBodyRows = getBodyRows(table);

    for (let nix = 0; nix < navAs.length; nix++) {

        if (nix == page - 1)
            navAs[nix].classList.add('active');
        else 
            navAs[nix].classList.remove('active');

        for (let trix = 0; trix < tBodyRows.length; trix++) 
            tBodyRows[trix].style.display = 
                (trix >= startItem && trix < endItem)
                ? 'table-row'
                : 'none';  

    }

}

// tbody might still capture header rows if 
// if a thead was not created explicitly.
// This filters those rows out.
function getBodyRows(table) {
    let initial = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
  return Array.from(initial)
    .filter(row => row.querySelectorAll('td').length > 0);
}
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse }
th { background-color: gainsboro; }
td { border: 0.5px solid gray; }
tfoot { background-color: whitesmoke; }
```

```html
<table id='someTable'>
  <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
  <tr><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
  <tr><td>g</td><td>h</td></tr>
  <tr><td>i</td><td>j</td></tr>
  <tr><td>k</td><td>l</td></tr>
  <tr><td>m</td><td>n</td></tr>
  <tr><td>o</td><td>p</td></tr>
  <tr><td>q</td><td>r</td></tr>
  <tr><td>s</td><td>t</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any chance of a fixed header? Or a header visible on all pages?

Comment: @Ciprian.  Sure.  It really did this before but I believe you may have applied it to a table without an explicit `<thead>` tag.  I modified it to work with `<th>` tags inside a `<tbody>` row, which is common.

Comment: You are right, I didn't have an explicit `<thead>` tag. It's now working properly. Thanks!

Comment: thank you @pwilcox, I loved your idea to hide the rows of inactive pages. you've got a star on github too.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this function . Its taken from https://convertintowordpress.com/simple-jquery-table-pagination-code/

```
function pagination(){
    var req_num_row=10;
    var $tr=jQuery('tbody tr');
    var total_num_row=$tr.length;
    var num_pages=0;
    if(total_num_row % req_num_row ==0){
        num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
    }
    if(total_num_row % req_num_row >=1){
        num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
        num_pages++;
        num_pages=Math.floor(num_pages++);
    }
    for(var i=1; i<=num_pages; i++){
        jQuery('#pagination').append("<a href='#' class='btn'>"+i+"</a>");
    }
    $tr.each(function(i){
        jQuery(this).hide();
        if(i+1 <= req_num_row){
            $tr.eq(i).show();
        }

    });
    jQuery('#pagination a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $tr.hide();
        var page=jQuery(this).text();
        var temp=page-1;
        var start=temp*req_num_row;
        //alert(start);

        for(var i=0; i< req_num_row; i++){

            $tr.eq(start+i).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a easy way to paginate a table using [breedjs](http://jjppof.github.io/breedjs) (jQuery plugin), see the example:

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr b-scope="people" b-loop="person in people" b-paginate="5">
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
      <td>{{person.age}}</td>
      <td>{{person.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<ul></ul>
```

JS

```
var data={ people: [ {...}, {...}, ...] };

$(function() {
  breed.run({
    scope: 'people',
    input: data,
    runEnd: function(){ //This runEnd is just to mount the page buttons
        for(i=1 ; i<=breed.getPageCount('people') ; i++){
        $('ul').append(
            $('<li>',{
            html: i,
            onclick: "breed.paginate({scope: 'people', page: " + i + "});"
          })
        );
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Every time you want to change pages, just call:

```
breed.paginate({scope: 'people', page: pageNumber);
```

[More info](http://jjppof.github.io/breedjs/#b-paginate).

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jjppof/h2epjt6f/).

Answer (score 1):

Just extending @anushree's answer with bootstrap 4 version.:-

just call pagination wherever you want.

```
function Pagination() {
    $('#table').after('<nav id="nav" aria-label="Page navigation example"></nav><ul class="pagination"></ul>');
    var rowsShown = 20;
    var rowsTotal = $('#table tbody tr').length;
    console.log("rowsTotal"),rowsTotal
    var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
    for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        $('.pagination').append('<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void()" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum + '</a></li> ');
    }
    $('#table tbody tr').hide();
    $('#table tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
    $('.pagination a:first').addClass('active');
    $('.pagination a').bind('click', function () {

        $('.pagination a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
        var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
        var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
        $('#table tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
            css('display', 'table-row').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
    });
}
```

Comment: I called the function after loaded my table data in jquery method and it worked succesfully!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it on the website of that paginations plugin, the plugin itself doesn't do the *actual* pagination. The only thing it does is display a row of numbers, and display the correct buttons depending on the page you're on.

However, to actually paginate, you have to write the appropriate Javascript yourself. This should be placed in stead of this Javascript:

```
function test(pageNumber)
{

  var page="#page-id-"+pageNumber;
  $('.select').hide()
  $(page).show()

}
```

Which is code I'm guessing you've copy-pasted from somewhere but at the moment doesn't really do anything. If you don't know Javascript, going with another library that actually does pagination of a table is something you probably want to do.

Answer (score 0):

With Reference to Anusree answer above and with respect,I am tweeking the code little bit to make sure it works in most of the cases.

1. Created a reusable function paginate('#myTableId') which can be called any number times for any table.
2. Adding code inside ajaxComplete function to make sure paging is called once table using jquery is completely loaded. We use paging mostly for ajax based tables.
3. Remove Pagination div and rebind on every pagination call
4. Configuring Number of rows per page

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        paginate('#myTableId',10);
        function paginate(tableName,RecordsPerPage) {
            $('#nav').remove();
            $(tableName).after('<div id="nav"></div>');
            var rowsShown = RecordsPerPage;
            var rowsTotal = $(tableName + ' tbody tr').length;
            var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
            for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
                var pageNum = i + 1;
                $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
            }
            $(tableName + ' tbody tr').hide();
            $(tableName + ' tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
            $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
            $('#nav a').bind('click', function () {

                $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
                var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
                var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
                $(tableName + ' tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
                    css('display', 'table-row').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` to `<tr  class="paginate">`

//Pagination

```
<div id="page-nav"></div>
```

//Script

```
 <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            // Grab whatever we need to paginate
            var pageParts = $(".paginate");
    
            // How many parts do we have?
            var numPages = 100;
            // How many parts do we want per page?
            var perPage = 10;
    
            // When the document loads we're on page 1
            // So to start with... hide everything else
            pageParts.slice(perPage).hide();
            // Apply simplePagination to our placeholder
            $("#page-nav").pagination({
                items: numPages,
                itemsOnPage: perPage,
                cssStyle: "light-theme",
                // We implement the actual pagination
                //   in this next function. It runs on
                //   the event that a user changes page
                onPageClick: function(pageNum) {
                    // Which page parts do we show?
                    var start = perPage * (pageNum - 1);
                    var end = start + perPage;
    
                    // First hide all page parts
                    // Then show those just for our page
                    pageParts.hide()
                        .slice(start, end).show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```