# How to make table with navigation in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Can I make a table with navigation?

So, if I have a 20 tr in my table, and I just want to show `10 data`, and then the table have a next button to next data. Can I do that?

I make it in Java (I make jsp page)

```
try {
    int i = 1;
    while (hasilQuery.next()) {
      hasil += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + hasilQuery.getString("nik")
             + "</td><td>" + hasilQuery.getString("nama")
             + "</td><td>" + hasilQuery.getString("jeniskelamin")
             + "</td>"
             + "<td><a href='detail.jsp?nik="+hasilQuery.getString("nik")+"'"
             + "><img height='20' src='img/detail.png' title='detail' /></a><a href='edit.jsp?nik="+hasilQuery.getString("nik")+"'><img src='img/edit.png' height='20' title='edit' /></a> "
             + "<a href='delete.jsp?nik="+hasilQuery.getString("nik")+"'><img src='img/hapus.png' height='20' title-'hapus' /></a></td></tr>";
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Hope the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605078/how-to-use-pagination-on-html-tables) will guide you for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> while (hasilQuery.next()) {
> ```

As well as stopping when you run out of results, stop when you have hit 10 results.

Then, if you haven't run out of results, add a link at the end:

```
<a href="?page=2">Page 2</a>
```

Now go back to the top of the code and check that query string parameter. If you have a value for it, use it to skip an appropriate number of results before you start outputting.

Then just change the "2" to be a dynamic value (also based on the value used to request the page). You'll probably want to add a previous link too.

… and that's the basics.

---

You'll probably want to move the logic for finding the 10 items you want into the database query instead of fetching all the results and then skipping a bunch in the Java.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery detach() to remove rows and insert them at the click event of your button.

Comment: do you have the link that describe it?