# how i can dived page in freemarker ( the page is tall and want to have next and previse button )

Tags: freemarker

I have a freemarker page but it is too long it is a list of items, so i would like to divide the page to more than one or have something link next and previse page. anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is to put the list as a HTML table that contains pagination to it so that it can take care of the next and previous page data. For pagination on HTML you can refer the below answer [How to use pagination on HTML tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605078/how-to-use-pagination-on-html-tables)